# I need to disable the Save as PDF option from print in chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome, security, printing, registry

I need to disable the option to "Save as PDF" in Chrome. If this option is selected, the user can then browse the file explorer, and we want to ensure we lock that down and have a single defined printer selection available. I have tried using the "PrintTypeDenyList" with no luck. I'm uncertain if it even works and can't find any other Chrome options through blogs online. https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/?policy=PrinterTypeDenyList

Has anyone been able to disable the Save as PDF print option in Chrome?

Thank you

Comment: If the chrome is managed by your enterprise, only then the mentioned policy applies.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran that's why that wasn't working... thanks for the clarification. Still need to find a good workaround to it.